# What is the difference in storage of a usb flash drive and sd card?

Tags: usb, flash, storage

So I am working on a usb mass storage driver, but I am using a sd card to test it.
I don't know if the same driver will be able to fetch the data from a USB drive, as the theory about usb flash storage I am unable to find.
For e.g SD card have some registers, which tells about its capacity and other parameters to the host, i.e PC, but is it same way in USB storage?

Comment: If *you* are working on such a driver you really should invest some time in reading and researching the subject. That is by reading the specs and not by asking some random broad questions.

Comment: I have tried to find, but it seems there is very less information regarding storage access.

Comment: USB mass storage is essentially treated as a SCSI device...you could start here: http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/Mass_Storage_Specification_Overview_v1.4_2-19-2010.pdf  ....there is a mass of information available (excuse the pun).

Answer (score 1):

There is lots of detail missing from your question (including about the *specific* hardware being used). However I can explain one part which, from your question, seems to be missing from your understanding of the overall system - hopefully this will help you:

> I am working on a usb mass storage driver, but I am using a sd card to test it.

In that case there must be, somewhere in your hardware, a USB-SD controller. This is because, as you seem know, the SD command protocol is different from the USB MSD (mass storage device) protocol (and obviously they are electrically different too).

In many cases, the USB-SD controller is a separate IC. For example, such ICs are used in typical USB "card readers" and also in laptops.

There are (were?) a few SD cards which included a normal SD connector, and also a ("flip-out") USB connector at the other end of the card. Those SD cards effectively include a USB-SD controller (and a PCB-only USB type-A plug) within the physical SD card.

> SD card have some registers, which tells about its capacity and other parameters to the host, i.e PC

Yes, but that information is used by the **SD host**. In the case of an SD card connected to a USB-SD controller, the SD host is *that* controller, *not* the USB host (e.g. the PC). Depending on the USB-SD controller IC, you might have no way to access the SD card's internal registers using the USB MSD protocol from the USB host - unless that USB-SD controller offers a vendor-specific way to send specific SD card commands within special USB commands (some have this feature).

From the USB-side of USB-SD controller, for normal USB MSD operations, you don't need to know anything about the SD card or its protocol, since that is "abstracted" by the controller, so the SD card *appears* to be a USB MSD.

This is similar to USB-attached hard disk drives. Those disk drives will usually use a SATA interface, but somewhere (e.g. inside an external disk enclosure, but sometimes on the disk drive's PCB itself) there will be a USB-SATA controller, which abstracts (hides) the specific of the SATA interface, so the (underlying SATA) disk drive, appears as a USB MSD to the USB host device.

As already highlighted in the comments, depending on *exactly* what you are trying to do, and where *exactly* you are struggling, the topic(s) you need to research will vary.